# Why MySql service doesn't start on WAMP?

Tags: mysql, wamp, innodb

I have a problem with wamp, yesterday was fine, but today the service doesn't start. I get the following file log.

```
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-02-04 11:49:26 944 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 1594  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/contacto'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."contacto"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 1594  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/equipo'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."equipo"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 1594  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/sidebar'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."sidebar"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 1594  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/slider'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:28 944 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."slider"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:29 944 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-02-04 11:49:29 944 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: Error: tablespace id is 965 in the data dictionary
InnoDB: but in file .\bjc\contenido_hijo.ibd it is 944!
2014-02-04 11:49:29 bcc  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 3020 in file fil0fil.cc line 794
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-02-04 11:49:53 5768 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 87c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/contacto'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."contacto"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 87c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/equipo'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."equipo"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 87c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/sidebar'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."sidebar"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 87c  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/slider'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2014-02-04 11:49:55 5768 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"bjc"."slider"', ignored.
2014-02-04 11:49:56 5768 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-02-04 11:49:56 5768 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
InnoDB: Error: tablespace id is 965 in the data dictionary
InnoDB: but in file .\bjc\contenido_hijo.ibd it is 944!
2014-02-04 11:49:56 540  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 1344 in file fil0fil.cc line 794
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

And I have no idea of what this means. Is the first time this happens to me, and I haven't found the reason or maybe didn't look for it enough.
Hope you can help me.
Thank you

Comment: did you try restarting the machine?

Comment: @Scrooj Do you mean the pc or the services?

Comment: I mean the PC..moreoften than not that should be the solution..probably your PC has been running for a few days

Comment: @Scrooj didn't work. But I guess is because a table `InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'bjc/contacto'. ` but how can I fix it if I can't access to mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to fixed this problem. Thankfully I had a sql script as a backup for the database that was causing this problem, so I deleted the folder with the name of the database in the dir `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data` and then restared the services, and restored the database with a different name. I guess that the OS damaged this files cause I had troubles earlier, I think my best option is to backup and re-install. Thank you for your help. 
Advice: Backup all your databases when you think they're ready.